# How to get to spit out a function multiple times in Python?

Tags: python

**What do I want to do?**

I want to have a palindrome in the shape of a pyramid. I can get the bottom layer of the pyramid with my code, but I don't know how to shape a for loop that will spit out x amount of lines with a palindrome in the shape of a pyramid.

**Example:**

```
a
aba
abcba
abcdcba
abcdedcba
```

and so on...

**My code:**

```
end_letter = 0 # is this correct?

def test_palindrome(end_letter):
    print call_palindrome(end_letter) + call_palindrome_second_part(end_letter)

def call_palindrome(end_letter):

    letters_from_a_to_y = ""           

    for letter in range(97,end_letter):
        letters_a_to_y += chr(letter) 

    return(letters_a_to_y)

def call_palindrome_second_part(end_letter): 

    letters_y_to_a = ""

    for letter in range(end_letter,96,-1): 
        letters_y_to_a += chr(letter)

    return(letters_y_to_a)

test_palindrome(end_letter)
```

How can I get this code working? What am I doing wrong and what am I missing?

Comment: `end_letter` isn't initialized before you use it, I'm guessing you need to do something like `end_letter=98` before you call `test_palindrome(end_letter)`

Comment: What do you mean? I mean, do I need to define that globally? That's my whole problem actually: I don't know whether it should be defined globally or in some method. Can someone explain that please?

Comment: yes in this case you need to define `end_letter` globally for it to be used in test_palindrome

Comment: Hate the fact that people are downvoting this. It's a legitimate question from a newbie who wants help. Where would I need to go otherwise? Damn. Anyway, I did that... thanks, it makes sense now. Can someone help me with the last bit? How do I iterate it to get a pyramid?

Comment: Should `letters_from_a_to_y` be `letters_a_to_y` in function `call_palindrome`

Comment: You defined your functions with a parameter named ```end_letter```; the functions' code expects ```end_letter``` to be an integer; when you call those functions, you need to call them with an integer or a name/variable that has had an integer assigned to it - ```end_letter = 8```.

Comment: @wwii, yes, so you'd expect something like: print test_palindrome(8)... but this just gives me 'none' in the console.

Comment: You need to determine the width of the base of the pyramid in advance then add spaces before and after the strings to center them on the base.

Comment: @wwii: I'll solve the width part, but my problem right now is that it just spits out the method once... how can I solve that? Do I need a for lope in the first method?

Comment: ```spits out the method once.``` - that is not very clear, when we see ```method``` we think a class attribute that is a function - you will have to explain that.

Comment: If you need to do something multiple times you will need to include some type of loop/iteration.

Comment: Yes, but where? In this case... where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the corrected program:

```
def palindromeGen(end_letter):
    print(call_palindrome(end_letter) + call_palindrome_second_part(end_letter))

def call_palindrome(end_letter):

    letters_a_to_y = ""           

    for letter in range(97,end_letter):
        letters_a_to_y += chr(letter) 

    return(letters_a_to_y)

def call_palindrome_second_part(end_letter): 

    letters_y_to_a = ""

    for letter in range(end_letter,96,-1): 
        letters_y_to_a += chr(letter)

    return(letters_y_to_a)

def test_palindrome(ch):
    for i in range(ord('a'), ord(ch)+1):
        palindromeGen(i)

test_palindrome('e')
```

Explanation:

- Bug in `call_palindrome()`: `letters_from_a_to_y --> letters_a_to_y`
- `end_letter` is an argument, you supplied it as a variable. Either you give it the value (like `ord('e')`) or assign the same.
- Once you are able to produce one line, you could iterate it over multiple lines. I've converted your `test_palindrome()` to `palindromeGen()` and coded a new one for this process.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

You are confused about how to call a function.

Defining a function:

```
def giveValue(x):
    return(x)
```

Calling a function:

```
 giveValue(4)

 OUTPUT: 4
```

or:

```
 a = 4
 giveValue(a)

 OUTPUT: 4
```